# Can I install latte dock in gnome DE?

Tags: gnome, kde, latte-dock

Latte dock is commonly used in KDE desktop environment.But themes of latte dock is always available in the gnome themes store. Am I able to install it on gnome? In 20.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latte-dock package is [available in *universe* pocket of repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=latte%20dock) since 18.04 LTS.

To install it use:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install latte-dock
```

I have just tested it on GNOME and MATE. So it can be installed and used.
You may need to customize the desktop environment by moving some components and panels.